# HTML - front page image shows up on tablet & phone but not on PC?

Tags: html, css

I have put an image on the front page of my website, as the header. This comes up on tablet and phone, but it doesn't come up on PC (using Chrome as the browser). This indicates it isn't a problem with the URL, but I'm not sure what exactly is wrong. I should add that it also shows up locally perfectly fine but not on the website.

```
<div id="adbox">
<div class="clearfix">
                <img src="images/About.png" border="0" alt="Img" height="371" width="956"/>
</div>
</div>
```

adbox CSS:

```
/** Adbox **/

#adbox {
    background: url(/images/bg-adbox.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#adbox > div {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    width: 958px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#adbox > div img {
    float: right;
}
#adbox .detail {
    font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    height: 185px;
    line-height: 48px;
    width: 308px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 54px;
    top: 90px;
}
#adbox .detail h1 {
    color: #4e5944;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: none;
}
#adbox .detail p {
    color: #4e5944;
    font: 25px/48px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you are using an adblock extension on your PC browser. to avoid that issue try to rename the id "#adbox" to something else that doesn't contain the "ad" keyword or disable your adblock.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you very much!